# Script in `/etc/init` is not executed

Tags: debian, init.d, etc

I added script `/etc/init/trackpoint.conf` and it contains:

```
description "Trackpoint-Settings"
env TPDIR=/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2
start on filesystems  # also tried on virtual-filesystems and local-filesystems
script
  echo "started" >> /home/user/file
end script
```

(`TPDIR` is not actually used)

I expect to see "started" in file `/home/user/file`, but nothing is there.
Ideas?

`uname -a` is: `Linux hell 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1):

Use instead `systemd` way of creating start up jobs
(`/etc/init` is for [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) solution, which seems to be deprecated)
([systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) is a replacement of [SysV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style)).

And here is how:

1. create `/etc/systemd/system/trackpoint.service` with

   [Unit]
   Description="Trackpoint-Settings"

   [Service]
   Type=forking
   ExecStart=/home/user/trackpoint.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target

where `trackpoint.sh` is what should be executed.

2. Then run:
   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
   `sudo systemctl enable trackpoint.service`

(inspired by malo answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable this service with `systemctl enable` 
And you can list and should find you service with `systemctl list-unit-files|grep trackpoint`

Comment: Thanks for hints, but could not make it run yet: `systemctl enable trackpoint` returns `Access denied`. The version `sudo systemctl enable trackpoint` says `No such file or directory`.... (it searches for trackpoint.service file which does not exist)